# Sqlalchemy core: reformat the select query inside select

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy core as below:

```
book = sa.Table(...)
student = sa.Table(...)
title_query = sa.select([book.c.title]).where(book.c.id=3).alias('a');
fee_query = sa.select([student.c.fee]).where(student.c.id=4).alias('b');
main_query = sa.select([title_query, fee_query])
```

Sqlalchemy is formatting the query as following:

```
SELECT a.title, b.fee
FROM (SELECT title FROM book WHERE id=3) as a,
     (SELECT fee FROM student WHERE id=4) as b;
```

Instead, I want to format it as following:

```
SELECT (SELECT title FROM book WHERE id=3),
       (SELECT fee FROM student WHERE id=4);
```

Because in the second formatting case, I'll get a tuple, even if one of the subselects returns 0 rows.

Comment: @Laurenz. I am implementing it in order to minimize the database calls. Are there any better way of doing it?

Comment: To the immediate issue at hand, `alias()` produces a selectable meant to be used in the FROM clause. Just remove it.

Comment: removing alias generates an error saying `asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: subquery in FROM must have an alias`

Comment: Replace `alias` with `as_scalar`. I tend to forget when it's required and when it's not.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thank you. It worked. Add it as answer with explaination, I'll accept the answer.